# Program to find the number of whitespaces and newlines characters

Tags: c++

how to Program to find the number of white spaces and newlines characters in c++ ?? 
that what i have so far....

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  int w = 0;
  char a[] = {' ', '\n'};
  char x[30],z[30];

  for (int i = 0 ; i <= 30;i++)
    cin >> x[i];

  for (int j = 0 ; j < 30; j++) {
    for (int k = 0 ; k < 2; k++) {
      x[j] == a[k];
      if (x[j] == ' ')
        w++;
    }
  }

  cout << w << endl;
  system("pause");
  return  0;
}
```

Comment: [std::isspace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/)

Comment: [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: And what is the problem with the program?

Comment: Why are you writing in C++85? God this code looks bad. Use `std::count_if` please.

Comment: Why are you using arrays?  You don't need to store all the characters read.

Comment: If you use `std::count_if` together with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) you could do it all in two statements.

Comment: Just as an FYI, in C++ and most other languages you're allowed to use variables that are longer than one character! But, seriously, please use words/multiple words for variable names. Remember that you'll be reading the code far more than you'll be typing it, so readability is extremely important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example showing the fundamental algorithm.  As others have commented, there are more simple and efficient methods.

```
int main(void)
{
  char c;
  unsigned int space_quantity = 0;
  unsigned int newline_quantity = 0;
  while (cin >> c) // Read in the character.
  {
    switch (c)
    {
      case ' ':  //  Check for space.
        ++space_quantity;
        break;

      case '\n':  // Check for newline.
        ++newlines;
        break;

      default:  // Don't do anything for other characters.
        break;
    }
  }
  cout << "Spaces: " << space_quantity << '\n';
  cout << "Newlines: " << newline_quantity << '\n';
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the above program, I used `switch` versus `if-else-if` because I thought it looked more readable.  You may not have learned about the `switch` statement, so you can use multiple `if` statements to check for the characters.  Same intention; maybe same executable code and performance.

**Edit 1:  Using arrays**
Arrays can improve the performance of I/O, by reading more than one character per input request.  Searching through memory is much faster than reading from an input source (not memory as the input source).

If you **must** use arrays, here is an example using arrays.  In general arrays are not used with `cin` due to the slow response of the User.

```
#define ARRAY_CAPACITY 128

int main(void)
{
  char c;
  unsigned int space_quantity = 0;
  unsigned int newline_quantity = 0;
  char         buffer[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
  while (cin.read(buffer, ARRAY_CAPACITY))
  {
     // Need to get the number of characters
     // actually read into the buffer.
     const unsigned int characters_read = cin.gcount();

     // Process each character from the buffer.
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < characters_read; ++i)
     {
       switch (c)
       {
         case ' ':  //  Check for space.
           ++space_quantity;
           break;

         case '\n':  // Check for newline.
           ++newlines;
           break;

         default:  // Don't do anything for other characters.
           break;
       } // End: switch
     } // End: for
  } // End: while
  cout << "Spaces: " << space_quantity << '\n';
  cout << "Newlines: " << newline_quantity << '\n';
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now when you have accepted a solution, I will show you the easiest and simplest way to do the same with the help of the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) in modern C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int spaces_and_newlines = 
        std::count_if(
            std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
            std::istream_iterator<char>(),
            [](const char& ch) { return (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n'); });
    std::cout << "Number of spaces and newlines: " << spaces_and_newlines << '\n';
}
```

References:

- [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
- [Lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Everything except lambda expressions are part of the C++03 standard, which all modern (and not so modern) compilers support. Lambda expressions are new in C++11 and is supported by all modern and popular C++ compilers (GCC 4.8, Clang 3.4, VisualC++ 2013 (I think the previous versions of all those compilers also have support for it), other up-to-date compilers (like Intels ICC) should also have support for it).

***However:*** There is a problem with this code, and with yours too: When reading from text input streams (like `std::cin`) using the input operator `>>` (or using input iterators like I do) the stream ***skips all whitespace***, which includes space and newline. Therefore your original, and my solution, can't be used for this, at least not for whitespace. That is why you have to use [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read characters, as it will not skip whitespace.

---

I didn't think of it at the time I wrote the answer, but you *can* use my program, but instead of using `std::istream_iterator` you can use [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator). Or [clear the `skipws` flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/unsetf).